How to listen to KeyboardEvent depending on an Observable value?
I am new to angular and I struggle with Observables. I searched for my question but I didn't find an answer for my exact problem.
I'm trying to enable/disable keyboard events depending on a variable (Observable) I get from the store.
...

isDisabled$: Observable<boolean> = this.store.select(selectIsDisabled);

private subscriptions = new Subscription();

constructor(
  private store: Store<IStore>
) {
  this.onKeyboardEvent();
}

...
// this.subscriptions is used in other functions
...

private onKeyboardEvent(): void {
  let keys: string[] = [];
    this.subscriptions.add(
      fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, 'keydown').pipe(
        filter(key => key.repeat === false),
        map(key => key.code)
      ).subscribe(keyCode => {
        if (!keys.includes(keyCode)) {
          keys.push(keyCode);
        }

        // Here we have keys pressed logic...

      })
    );
}

Here is my code now, what I want to achieve is to enable/disable keyboard events depending on isDisabled$ value (I have a button to change isDisabled$ value).
I tried to subscribe to isDisabled$ and call this.onKeyboardEvent() when isDisabled is false but the problem is this.subscriptions still have fromEvent event even when isDisabled is true.
I tried also to unsubscribe this.subscriptions when isDisabled === true but this didn't work for me
I am new to angular & rxjs I don't know if there's an operator to achieve this?
Thanks for your help :)

You can try combineLatest like this:
  keyDown$ = fromEvent<KeyboardEvent>(document, 'keydown').pipe(
    map((key) => key.code)
  );
  filteredKeyDown$ = combineLatest([this.isDisabled$, this.keyDown$]).pipe(
    filter(([isDisabled, _]) => !isDisabled),
    map(([_, key]) => key)
  );

When it comes to unsubscribing the best way these days is to use takeUntilDestroyed
private onKeyboardEvent(): void {
  this.filteredKeyDown$.pipe(takeUntilDestroyed()).subscribe(...);
}

Obviously i don't know your exact use case, but maybe you can provide isDisabled property as an input signal through the async pipe? I'm not 100% sure I didn't tested that. By doing so you can avoid handling subscription which is usually a better choice.
<app-component [isDisabled]="isDisabled$ | async"/>

...
isDisabled = input.required<boolean>();

@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
handleKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (this.isDisabled()) return;
  ...
}

